# How do I move twitter configuration out of the controller? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am using the [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) by sferik.

I think it's very messy to store the configuration for my twitter app in the controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController


  def index
    require "twitter"
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "###"
      config.consumer_secret     = "###"
      config.access_token        = "###"
      config.access_token_secret = "###"
    end
    @tweets = client.user_timeline( count: 2)
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

I'm attempting to store this in /config/initializers/twitter_creds.rb:

```
require "twitter"
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "###"
      config.consumer_secret     = "###"
      config.access_token        = "###"
      config.access_token_secret = "###"
    end
```

But I'm not sure if this is right or how I would access the twitter client within my controller. I've noticed that some developers use .yml files to store configuration files. I'm looking for guidance; what's best practice and how do I access the Twitter client from my controller?

Comment: is there an expiration time for the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About your class:**

Is better you use a module to encapsulate the twitter logic. I would change the class like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  include MyTwitterModule

  def index
    @tweets = user_timeline(2)
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

and the module would be like this:

```
require "twitter"
module MyTwitterModule
  @@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = "###"
    config.consumer_secret     = "###"
    config.access_token        = "###"
    config.access_token_secret = "###"
  end

  def user_timeline(qt)
    @@client.user_timeline(count: qt)
  end
end
```

this is only a sugestion ;)

**About store keys and tokens:**

The better way to store this kind of information is using Rails.env, with this you can use different keys or tokens for development and production and its not storaged in file.

Take a look at this [gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), its can help you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm getting "undefined method `user_timeline' for nil:NilClass". Any idea what's going on?

Comment: have you solved this error message: "undefined method `user_timeline' for nil:NilClass"? I'm in same predicament

Comment: This code is not tested I pressume. If you really want it exactly like this, you need a class variable instead, i.e. `@@client` instead of `@client`. Otherwise, the instance variable will be lost everytime. @wali-ali

Comment: You are right @Ron, I not tested the code :). I Updated the answer. Thank you dude.

Comment: Why is it better to use a module instead of an initialiser? Is there some information anywhere about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had difficulty including this as a module, so added it to my model instead.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def user_timeline(qt)
    twitter_client = initialize_twitter_client
    twitter_client.user_timeline(count: qt)
  end

  private

    def initialize_twitter_client
      Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key        = "###"
        config.consumer_secret     = "###"
        config.access_token        = "###"
        config.access_token_secret = "###"
      end
    end

end


class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = #however you get the user
    @tweets = @user.user_timeline(2)
  end

end
```