# Rails app with Twitter API: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm trying to integrate my app with twitter API.

here are my steps:

1: installed the twitter gem: `gem 'twitter`

2:grabbed [this](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) code from the twitter gem documentation and placed it inside my `controller`. I also tried placing the code in a `helper`.

`require 'twitter'`

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key    = ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"]
  config.consumer_secret = ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
  config.access_token        = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  config.access_token_secret = ENV["ACCESS_SECRET"]
end
```

3) registered my app with twitter and got the `consumer_key (AKA: API key)`, `consumer_secret (AKA:API secret)`, `access_token`, and `access_token_secret`.

I used a `config/application.yml` to store access tokens. is that correct way of doing it? I hope so.

4) in `views`, I have `<%= @client.user.username %>`.

I'm doing this in development (localhost3000). my callback url is `http://127.0.0.1/`

I also tried to organize my code as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570676/how-do-i-move-twitter-configuration-out-of-the-controller-rails) suggests to no avail.

I'm using `Rails 4.0.2`

I tested the code in the `console` and is working perfectly. I tried several queries including the one shown above: `<%= @client.user.username %>` and they are all working.

but when I run my code in development i get this error:

```
undefined method `user'` for nil:NilClass.
```

I understand what the error means. but how is it possible that @client is nil? when I run it in the console, it is not nil. Did I forget something? I would appreciate any suggestions. Please let me know if you would like me to provide more info/code. Thanks.

EDIT: Also, tried to move the above code that start with `@client` to a `config/initializers/twitter.rb`. Getting same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both solutions outlined here by @Pramod Shinde and @Peeyush, but none of them seemed to work for me. Here is how I solved the problem.

What I needed to do is to wrap a `method action` around the following code which I had inside my controller. Like this:

```
def tweets
  @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"]
    config.consumer_secret     = ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
    config.access_token        = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    config.access_token_secret = ENV["ACCESS_SECRET"]
  end
end
```

I created a new file, `config/application.yml` to store my `twitter API credentials`, and added the file to `.gitignore` to avoid it being commited to `github`. The above code uses `ENV[]` to access the credentials stored in `config/application.yml`.

`config/application.yml`:

```
CONSUMER_KEY: "1234"
CONSUMER_SECRET: "1234"
ACCESS_TOKEN: "1234"
ACCESS_SECRET: "1234"
```

This is a `YAML` file. So beware of the indentation.

Then inside my `routes.rb`, I created a route that maps to the above action:

```
get "/tweets", to: "posts#tweets"
```

Obviously, if you wanted to post tweets instead of fetching them, you'd have to create a `POST` route. You may also consider moving the above action to it's own `TweetsController`. Or encapsulate it in it's own class.

To complete the convention, I created a `view file` which maps to the `tweets` action:

```
tweets.html.erb
```

The reason why I was getting this error message:

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

is because I didn't have a `route`, `controller action`, and a `view file` that map to each.

Up until this point, everything is working fine when in `development`.

when I pushed the app to `heroku`, I got the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unable to verify your credentials):
```

Solution: install `gem 'figaro'` (actually this gem creates for you `config/application.yml` file and automatically appends it to `.gitignore`.

To solve the `heroku` error, all you have to do is run: `rake figaro:heroku`. See this [tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) about using the `figaro gem` to keep the environment variables private

Answer (score 1):

This may be because your controller code is trying to access `CONSUMER_KEY` etc. from environment variable but you have not set it in development mode.

You can use [rails_config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) gem and let it create the settings.yml file for you in `config/` with appropriate configurations.
] Now, store you twitter details in it as follows:

```
twitter:
  CONSUMER_KEY: 'your_consumer_key_here'
  CONSUMER_SECRET: 'your_consumer_secret_here'
  ACCESS_TOKEN: 'your_access_token_here'
  ACCESS_SECRET:'your_access_secret_here'
```

Then, modify your controller code to use those values as follows:

```
account = Settings['twitter']

@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = account["CONSUMER_KEY"]
  config.consumer_secret     = account["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
  config.access_token        = account["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  config.access_token_secret = account["ACCESS_SECRET"]
end
```

You can add `settings.yml` to `.gitignore` so that the file is not commited by git.

Or, you can use the approach described [Here](http://www.synaptian.com/blog/posts/using-the-twitter-gem-in-your-rails-application).

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code) if you are thinking of setting ENV variables in development.

Comment: is that under `config/settings.yml` or `config/initilizers/settings.yml`?

Comment: I moved the code to `config/settings.yml`, and used your code in the controller but i'm now getting new error: `uninitialized constant PostsController::Settings`. any idea?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have installed `gem "rails_config"`. Still going through the documentation trying to figure out how to use it. I'll try to figure it out tomorrow. any pointers on how I can use this gem to load my environment as it relates to my code is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your keys are not getting loaded properly

your config/settings.yml should look like this

```
development:
  twitter:  
    CONSUMER_KEY: 'your_consumer_key_here'
    CONSUMER_SECRET: 'your_consumer_secret_here'
    ACCESS_TOKEN: 'your_access_token_here'
    ACCESS_SECRET:'your_access_secret_here'
```

make this file as per your environments

Then Load this as

```
def get_twitter_client 
  oauth_config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml"))

  @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = oauth_config[Rails.env]['twitter']["CONSUMER_KEY"]
    config.consumer_secret     = oauth_config[Rails.env]['twitter']["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
    config.access_token        = oauth_config[Rails.env]['twitter']["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    config.access_token_secret = oauth_config[Rails.env]['twitter']["ACCESS_SECRET"]
  end
end
```

**Also if you look at Twitter gem @client has method user(user show API) which accepts user_id or twitter_username/handle/screen_name**

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Rails configuration is a topic I know almost nothing about. should `oauth_config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml"))` and the block of code that follows go inside `config/environments` folder?

Comment: no matter where I put this code, i'm still getting same error as before `undefined method user for ni:NilClass`

Comment: Put this code in some model and call it like `model_object.get_twitter_client` if you still getting this error log `@client.errors` and log `oauth_config[Rails.env]['twitter']["CONSUMER_KEY"]` and all other keys see if keys are getting loaded properly